# J2ME - Dynamic Table/Grid with editable cells.

Tags: java-me

How can I create a table in which I can add rows and columns dynamically?

How can I make cells of that dynamic table editable? I.e. I should push Edit Command button and write texts or numbers in the cell.

Comment: You mean to say that you need some functionality like spreadsheets?

Comment: You can implement it very easily. all that you need to have is a Graphics object. You have your data structures in your SpreadSheet class and pass the Graphics object, when you want to painting on the screen (esp when you are editing cell, deleting cell etc). Hope this helps, let me know if you need further more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is old, you may take a look at [MicroCalc](http://mixa.dev.juga.ru/microcalc/microcalc.htm) to get some ideas about the implementation.
It is a spreadsheet implemented in J2ME under GPL license.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/) which has one of the best listview implementations in J2ME

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no such UI control that is available in MIDP, you should either create the control or use some library such as [J2ME-Polish](http://www.j2mepolish.org/)